# LibXML: Comment-out a block of Elements

Tags: perl, libxml2

IS there a way to add/initate a comment ( e.g. $dom->createComment ... ) such that it comments out an entire block of xml tags.  Basically I want to turn-off the content between the comment.
For example, it would look like this:

```
      <TT>
        <AA>keep</AA>
        <!-- comment to blocking
        <BB>hideme1</BB>
        <CC>hideme2</CC>
        -->
        <DD>d's content is good</DD>
      </TT>
```

Actually this question is a pre-cursor to my attempt to figure-out a method to be able to markup/label/identify the changes to an xml files in support of new client software functionality, but be able to have the ability to remove / back-out these xml changes in the rare event the client needs to fall back to the previous software version (and no I can't just simply point back to the original xml file because the client is allowed to make minor modifications to existing node text values).  This is all going to be controlled via a perl script and LibXML's core modules (I can't use modules the client doesn't have).

So basically I've identified three possible types of xml changes as a result of new client sw functionality: 
1.) ADD new element node(s) (typically to support new sw functionality)
2.) DELETE element node(s), or blocks of (would be rare, but never-the-less a possibility)
3.) CHANGE node text values (rare, but the new sw may require a new value)

For all three types, the client needs the ability to back out the changes.  One thing I was thinking to use is ATTRIBUTES since the existing xml files don't use them.  For example, for an ADD change type, I could include an atribute like 'ADD="sw version 4.1"' . This way if it needs to be removed, I could just simply have the perl script find those attribute strings and delete them (using LibXML methods).  Same thing with CHANGE change type - I could use an attribute like CHG="newvalue_oldvalue", then again use straight perl (or LibXML) to switch back the value based on the contents of the attribute.  The DELETE change type is giving me a problem though (as welll as the others lol!).  I want to be able to "keep" the deleted lines in the xml file soley for the purposes if the sw falls back a version (at some late point the perl script could eventually cleanup/delete them).

I know this is a lot, I'm new to LibXML (but not to perl).  I was just wonder if any of you have any thoughts as to how to go about it or seen anything resembling this kind of request ... I'd be grateful for any kind of advice! Thank you...

Comment: 1) Find the XML serialization the nodes. 2) Create a comment whose value is that serialization. 3) Insert the comment in the document. 4) delete the nodes "converted" to a comment.

Comment: @ikegami  - Cool, i think I understand ... and insert as a comment to the parent of the first node I'm commenting out ... or to the sibling just above it ? Which way, or do I have to consider both types?

Comment: I'd use something like `$child->replaceNode($new)` or `$child->parentNode->insertAfter($child, $new)`.